# What happens if you force field but there's no more room?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

Suppose you have an area completely walled off with structures and filled with units, such that no more units can enter.

Then, you drop a force field on it. What happens?

Answer (score 7):

What happens... to what? To the structures, nothing. Any units pressed between the forcefield and the structures will just warp to the closest free position, but not across structures. Either that, or they will just stay where they are, unable to move.

Comment: Indeed - it's the same behavior as when you construct a building that's surrounded on all sides, the worker unable to escape. He will be trapped between buildings unable to move.

Comment: Don't think I've ever seen a unit warp due to forcefields... any example of that happening?

Comment: I think he means how they slide out of the way.

Comment: Yeah they will warp a short distance if trapped, or simply be stuck in place until the forcefields expire, if the distance is too great.

Answer (score 3):

Units that are forcefielded when there is no available space will stack on top of each other when necessary. See [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qe1bSjv7LgI) for an example.